# Printing array element every second

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know it sounds simple to most of you but it has been bugging me for a while now. I've been trying to loop through an array and its elements every second and do a function with the element being called out. But the result is always the loop printing all the elements at once.

This is what my code looks like. Sorry if its messy.

```
var ticking = window.setInterval(ticks, 1000);

function ticks() {
    var morse = ['.', '-', '-', '-', '-'];

    for (i = 0; morse.length > i; i++) {
      if (morse[i] == '.') {
        tickArrowDegree = 516;
        $('#tick-arrow').css({'transform': 'rotate(' + tickArrowDegree + 'deg)'});

        setTimeout(function reset() {
        $('#tick-arrow').css({'transform': 'rotate(' + startPoint + 'deg)'});
        }, 500);
      }
      else {
        tickArrowDegree = 522;
        $('#tick-arrow').css({'transform': 'rotate(' + tickArrowDegree + 'deg)'});

        setTimeout(function reset() {
        $('#tick-arrow').css({'transform': 'rotate(' + startPoint + 'deg)'});
        }, 500);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: " But the result is always the loop printing all the elements at once." What element are you printing?

Comment: `setTimeout()` queues up a function to be run later, it doesn't pause current execution. (So all of the timeouts run after your loop finishes.) The simplest change to your existing code would be to try setting the delay to `500 * i` instead of just to `500`.

Comment: I want to print the first element, have a pause, then print second and pause again, etc until all elements are printed out.

Comment: I multiplied it by i but it just printed the first element twice and it stopped there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes. You are saying you want to run that function every second. What happens in that function? You run through the whole array.

You probably want something like this. Just remove the for loop altogether and declare your iterator (`i`) outside the loop. https://jsfiddle.net/t82m8xog/

```
var ticking = window.setInterval(ticks, 1000);
var i = 0;
var startPoint=0;

function ticks() {
  var morse = ['.', '-', '-', '-', '-'];
  if (i >= morse.length) {
    clearInterval(ticking);    
    return;
  }

  if (morse[i] == '.') {
    tickArrowDegree = 516;
    $('#tick-arrow').css({
      'transform': 'rotate(' + tickArrowDegree + 'deg)'
    });

    setTimeout(function reset() {
      $('#tick-arrow').css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + startPoint + 'deg)'
      });
    }, 500);
  } else {
    tickArrowDegree = 522;
    $('#tick-arrow').css({
      'transform': 'rotate(' + tickArrowDegree + 'deg)'
    });

    setTimeout(function reset() {
      $('#tick-arrow').css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + startPoint + 'deg)'
      });
    }, 500);    
  }
  i++;
 }
```

Comment: I believe that this is supposed to work but on my side it prints "." and "-" at once the first second, then "-" 2 times the next second and "-" 2 more times the third second. It doesn't count to 5. I think its something on my end thats making a conflict in my code.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I had another duplicate ticking variable in my code that I didn't see. your solution was the best and I also didn't know about clearInterval so thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

I also searched for a solution for this and find a plugin to execute it.
Glad to share it to you :)

```js
/* ysm.array.js; Yan Morin <progysm@gmail.com>; 2014-12-09 */

if (!('ysm' in window)) {
    window.ysm = {};
}

ysm.array = {};

/**
 * Run a function for each item inside an array, using a timeout
 * @param Array arr
 * @param Function callback (parameters are value, index, array)
 * @param Number timems (in milliseconds)
 * @return undefined
 */
ysm.array.forEachTime = function(arr, callback, timems) {
    var i = 0;
    (function c() {
        if (i < arr.length) {
            callback(arr[i], i, arr);
            i++;
            setTimeout(c, timems);
        }
    })();
}

/**
 * Run a function for each item inside an array, infinitely, using a timeout
 * @param Array arr
 * @param Function callback (parameters are value, index, array)
 * @param Number timems (in milliseconds)
 * @return undefined
 */
ysm.array.forEachTimeLoop = function(arr, callback, timems) {
    var i = 0;
    (function c() {
        if (i < arr.length) {
            callback(arr[i], i, arr);
            i++;
            if (i === arr.length) {
                i = 0;
            }
            setTimeout(c, timems);
        }
    })();
}
var morse = ['.', '-', '-', '-', '-'];
ysm.array.forEachTime(morse, ticks, 1000)

var startPoint = 0;
function ticks(tick) {
 console.log(tick);
    if (tick == '.') {
        tickArrowDegree = 516;
        $('#tick-arrow').css({
            'transform': 'rotate(' + tickArrowDegree + 'deg)'
        });

        setTimeout(function reset() {
            $('#tick-arrow').css({
                'transform': 'rotate(' + startPoint + 'deg)'
            });
        }, 500);
    } else {
        tickArrowDegree = 522;
        $('#tick-arrow').css({
            'transform': 'rotate(' + tickArrowDegree + 'deg)'
        });

        setTimeout(function reset() {
            $('#tick-arrow').css({
                'transform': 'rotate(' + startPoint + 'deg)'
            });
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

```css
#tick-arrow {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tick-arrow" >
    ARROW
</div>
```